# MAX31865 & NodeMCU RTD Low Threshold and Exception

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I've got a NodeMCU V1 and a MAX31865 with a PT100 attached.  When using the example arduino code, it seems to log out the correct values but with an RTD Low Threshold error like so:

```
RTD value: 8068
Ratio = 0.24621582
Resistance = 105.87280273
Temperature = 15.09
Fault 0x40
RTD Low Threshold
```

The loop will continue for a few iterations and then throw an exception, before resuming logging out of the values above

The exception reads:

```
--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Soft WDT reset

>>>stack>>>

ctx: sys
sp: 3fffed00 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 01a0
3fffeea0:  38fe9521 00000000 3ffe8938 00000030  
3fffeeb0:  401015ea 3ffe88f4 004ae1cb 40233b68
etc etc etc
```

The code is as follows.

```
#include <Adafruit_MAX31865.h>

// Use software SPI: CS, DI, DO, CLK
Adafruit_MAX31865 thermo = Adafruit_MAX31865(D4,D1,D2,D3);
//Adafruit_MAX31865 thermo = Adafruit_MAX31865(D4);


#define RREF      430.0
#define RNOMINAL  100.0

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Adafruit MAX31865 PT100 Sensor Test!");
  thermo.begin(MAX31865_3WIRE);  // set to 2WIRE or 4WIRE as necessary
}


void loop() {
  uint16_t rtd = thermo.readRTD();
  Serial.print("RTD value: "); Serial.println(rtd);
  float ratio = rtd;
  ratio /= 32768;
  Serial.print("Ratio = "); Serial.println(ratio,8);
  Serial.print("Resistance = "); Serial.println(RREF*ratio,8);
  Serial.print("Temperature = "); Serial.println(thermo.temperature(RNOMINAL, RREF));

  // Check and print any faults
  uint8_t fault = thermo.readFault();
  if (fault) {
    Serial.print("Fault 0x"); Serial.println(fault, HEX);
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_HIGHTHRESH) {
      Serial.println("RTD High Threshold"); 
    }
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_LOWTHRESH) {
      Serial.println("RTD Low Threshold"); 
    }
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_REFINLOW) {
      Serial.println("REFIN- > 0.85 x Bias"); 
    }
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_REFINHIGH) {
      Serial.println("REFIN- < 0.85 x Bias - FORCE- open"); 
    }
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_RTDINLOW) {
      Serial.println("RTDIN- < 0.85 x Bias - FORCE- open"); 
    }
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_OVUV) {
      Serial.println("Under/Over voltage"); 
    }
    thermo.clearFault();
  }
  Serial.println();
  delay(10000);
}
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3SaWK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>